# How to disable a button initially then re-activate it during gameplay

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk, event-listener

I'm developing a shooter mobile app where if I click on the 'fire' button during the gameplay, it will shoot a bullet at the enemy object and destroy it. This 'fire' button is active throughout the gameplay and it shoots a bullet by only tapping on the button rather than holding the button continuously.

At the moment, I want to create a 'secondary weapon' button, which fires in a similar fashion to the 'fire' button. However, I wish for this 'secondary weapon' button to be disabled initially until a specific enemy killed by the bullets from the 'fire' button activates it.

Essentially, is there a way to make a button be de-active initially (and appear transparent on screen) and then be activated to shoot after certain events have occurred?

Here's a sample of the 'fire' button that I'm using:

```
local function shootFn(e)

    if e.phase == "ended" then 

        local power = (firenum+2.5)/2 
        local bullet =   display.newImage("assets/game/fire/"..firenum..".png")
        bullet.x = player[1].x; bullet.y = player[1].y - 50
        bullet.power = power
        sceneGroup:insert(bullet)
        physics.addBody(bullet, "dynamic",{isSensor = true})
        bullet.isBullet = true;bullet.name = "bullet"
        bullet.speed = firenum * 7

        fireBtn:setEnabled(false)
        timer.performWithDelay(350,function() fireBtn:setEnabled(true); end, 1)
    end
end
```

Thanks guys! Appreciate the support :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [widget.newButton](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html)

```
btn:setEnabled(false)
```

should deactivate the button and you can just then reactivate it by

```
btn:setEnabled(true)
```

as you have above. If you want it to be invisible/transparent,

```
btn.alpha = 0.X
```

or

```
btn.isVisisble = false
```

Comment: Hi Dannash. That's right - I'm currently using the widget.newButton. My main concern is actually whereabouts I should be placing the "btn:setEnabled(false)" within the sample of code provided to make sure it whole button itself is disabled initially before it become active through an event.